# How to change the base link url in magento

Tags: magento, base-url

I have changed the `Base Link Url(base link url)` ( not the `base url`) . Now my site is not `accessible` except for the home page. How to solve this ? . This option is not visible in `core_config_data table` too.

I am using magento 1.8.

I changed it system -> web -> unsecured -> base link url .

Now I am not able to access anything in my site. as am getting two index.php in the url.

Comment: which version of magento that you are using ? Where did you make changes ? Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root folder and look for .htaccess

In that file scroll down (to line 123) a bit until you find a line of code that is commented out, should be similar to:

RewriteBase /magento/

Change that line to

RewriteBase /